# Changing existing pages in Agilo/Trac via plugin

Tags: python, trac

Is it possible to make changes to an existing page in Trac via a plugin?
(I am not talking about the wiki, but the ticket system).

I am trying to make a plugin that uses the View Tickets -> Custom Query view and gets the tickets from the resulting table of tickets. The goal is to use these tickets to modify them via a predefined python script, and then optionally print them.

Is this possible via the trac api or would one have to make a whole new page and write that whole query functionality from scratch to get the tickets from the database?

I feel that this is not very clearly documented by Trac, so I hope there are some people with experience in plugin development for trac and/or agilo for trac.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that [ITicketManipulator](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.ticket.api.ITicketManipulator) is [not called](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11723) in batch modify events. You might be able to implement a solution using [IRequestFilter](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.api.IRequestFilter). I'd need more information about how you plan to modify the tickets in order to give better advice.

Comment: What I want to do is get the tickets, filter desired information from them (for example I only need the summary and ID, but not the description), and then print them.

Comment: I already made a script that generates the HTML for how the printed page should look with the tickets arranged on them as a table, and so far I can use a .csv-file to import a list of tickets to the script. But now I want to make the script into a plugin and get the tickets directly from Trac instead of from the .csv-export.
That's why it would be great if I could use the existing "custom query" to get a list of tickets, and use that list of tickets with my script.

Comment: You might be able to implement `IContentConverter` in a plugin to add another link to bottom of the page in the section _Download in other formats_. See existing implementation in [query.py](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.8/trac/ticket/query.py#L872).

Comment: Is it possible to add that _Download in other formats_ link without changing query.py, so that I get the link when I install my plugin, but can uninstall it without changes to the core? Or can I only add the button to completely new modules that have their own page and their own navigation bar item, like Wiki, Timeline and View Tickets?

Comment: Yes, the intention of the extension point is to allow you to add a link to any page without changing the Trac code. Check out the documentation for [IContentConverter](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.mimeview.api.IContentConverter).

Comment: Do I need to change query.py and add the export option to `def get_supported_conversions(self):` and `def convert_content(self, req, mimetype, query, key):`? This would require the user of the plugin to overwrite their existing query.py, wouldn't it? Or can I somehow pack an altered version of query.py in my .egg that overrides the existing one?

Comment: Is it the ITemplateProvider that I need to implement in order to change the existing Query View?

Comment: You can write a plugin that implements the two methods of `IContentConverter`, extending the interface, not overwriting it. If this isn't familiar to you then you'll need to spend some time reviewing the documentation and examples that I've previously referenced, as well as [TracPlugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPlugins).